# Adding a custom keybinding in Doom Emacs

Tags: key-bindings, evil, doom

I am using evil-mode and am very new to emacs and doom. How would I be able to map Ctrl-s to `:w` or save. Also, how would I be able to bind Ctrl-n to `neotree-toggle`? I have been searching and trying for hours with no luck.

Comment: What have you been trying? It helps formulate better answers if there's more details in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(map! "C-s" 'basic-save-buffer)` - :w

`(map! "C-n" 'neotree-toggle)`

You need to find out what functions are mapped by evil-ex (e.g. :w). It is not documented anywhere other than source code.

Also be aware of complex keybinding precedence hierarchy every time you click a button in emacs.

> I am very new to emacs and doom.

For anyone else reading this may god help you